# Using the system's tap sound in a progressive web app

Tags: audio, click, progressive-web-apps

I've been working on a progressive web app, but I've noticed that unlike native apps, it doesn't produce tap sounds even if my phone has them enabled. For example, on my Android phone when I click an email it makes a little sound or vibrates.

Is there any way to access this API when building a web app or is this one of the limits of non-native app development?

Comment: You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/notification-behaviour#renotify). It stated that if you set `tag` and `renotify` to `true`, it will make new notifications vibrate and play a system sound.

Comment: @abielita I don't want to show a full push notification though. I just want to play the Android tap sound when the user clicks an item. Thanks for pointing me to those docs though. I'll dive in deeper and see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 0):

i shall explain using jquery

```js
<script>
var tapsound = new Audio('click_sound.mp3');
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#upload").click(function(){
         tapsound.play();
     });
});
</script>
```

```html
<button id="upload">Upload</button>
```